# Including functions from another internal .c file?

Tags: c

I made some program using structures and functions and now I have to split my work into 3 files as follows:

```
header.h - declaring data types, functions, #define
func.c - function definition,
main.c - structure array initialization and calling functions
```

Does it make sense to do it like that? I did that, added #include "header.h" in both .c files but it does not compile, seems there is something wrong with func.c. I'm using VS 2017.

Comment: Hiding the code and the error message while seeking for help, doesn't seem to be the best idea.

Comment: People in general do not possess psychic powers. Please provide a) the files and b) possible errors you're getting when you try to compile.

Comment: Yes it probably makes sense, and yes, there is something wrong with your code.

Comment: Did you run into compilation errors or linker errors?  If there were missing symbol linking errors, did you try to link both object files?  The scheme you outline should work, but you have to use it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Lets consider below example,

**header.h** : Normally user-defined  header file consist common information like MACRO, Structure, predefined header files which will be used by most of files in multiple file compilation.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
int n;
#define MAX 5
void call();

typedef enum legends {
        L_GANDHI,
        L_MARTIN_LUTHER_KING
}legends_e;
```

**main.c** :

```
#include"header.h"
int main()
{
        printf("in main() : %d \n",L_GANDHI);
        call();// defined in other file
        return 0;
}
```

**fun.c** :

```
#include"header.h"
void call()
{
        printf("In call() function : %d \n",L_MARTIN_LUTHER_KING);
}
```

for compiling all files,

```
xyz@xyz-PC:~/s_flow/john$ gcc main.c func.c
```

Remember that in multiple file compilation you should have only one main() function. I hope above information will give helps to solve your problem.